# Why am I seeing these traceback and Python related warnings after I installed Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I turn on my computer I always see this notification in a big window, but I don't know how to fix this.

I've tried several times to fix this, but the problem remains and I don't know what else to do.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 711, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/dbus_backend.py", line 375, in deal_message
    QueueMessageClient(self.config, self.scheduler).LogLogMetricEvent("FRONTEND", "Dell Linux Assistant closes")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/telemetry_common.py", line 300, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/queue_message_client.py", line 107, in LogLogMetricEvent
    return self.triggerSend(filePath, header, Schedule)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/queue_message_client.py", line 51, in triggerSend
    job = self.scheduler.add_interval_job(MessageHelper(self.configure).SendEvent, minutes=1, start_date=datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=1), args=[filePath, header], max_runs=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ApschedulerStandalone/scheduler.py", line 347, in add_interval_job
    return self.add_job(trigger, func, args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ApschedulerStandalone/scheduler.py", line 285, in add_job
    if not self.running:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ApschedulerStandalone/scheduler.py", line 148, in running
    thread_alive = self._thread and self._thread.isAlive()
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, i'm not very skilled with this. When I turn on my computer I always visualize this notification in a bit windows.

Comment: @SaaranshGarg my interpretation is that this is about some piece of software that's run automatically on Ubuntu startup and that OP _isn't_ doing any programming herself. Therefore it isn't appropriate for [so] (but may well need more detail to be answerable here)

Comment: Okay, @DavidW, when I added the comment the question didn't had the first line it has now. But yeah, the question still needs more clarity,

Comment: You said you have tried several times to solve this. What have you tried and what did you find during those tries?

Comment: Did you buy a Dell device that came with Ubuntu preinstalled?

Comment: @DanielB Yes I buy

Comment: @mtak I don't know how to explaine, but I searched in a lot foruns what is it, but I didn't understand

Answer (score 7):

The error message you see here comes from “Dell Linux Assistant”, which is apparently some software that Dell has decided to preinstall on machines that ship with Ubuntu.

The error is the result of a breaking change in Python 3.9. Dell Linux Assistant is not compatible with Python 3.9. You most likely got Python 3.9 when you upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10.

There are basically two ways forward:

1. Contact Dell Support and have them provide an updated version of the software
2. Remove the software

To remove it, [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372666), run the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt remove dell-recovery dell-linux-assistant
```

You will have to enter your user’s password when prompted.

You could also attempt to just prevent the software from starting automatically, but I have no information how it starts in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to keep these packages and update  them, add the ppa and do so. dell-linux-assistant has been maintained as of June 30, 2022.
[https://launchpad.net/~somerville-dla-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Esomerville-dla-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:somerville-dla-team/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Comment: After upgrading from ubuntu 20 to 22 I forgot to uncomment the repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, there was ppa:somerville-dla-team/ppa. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 had the same error message.
I unchecked in the "Startup Applications Preferences" Dell Linux Assistant.
The error message stopped.
Probably caused by some python version inconsistencies.